# VSCode opening output tab automatically when I typing code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

during typying code and auto save in vscode, output tab automatically running. It's so uncomfortable.

is there are anyone who give me some help?

[image]

I've been trying to my self but I didn't find solution

Answer (score 0):

This happens when code-runner extension is installed in vs code.
Disable code-runner extension and reload the vs code.